# Bloomberg Historical low value interval

Tags: .net, bloomberg

I am trying to find the lowest price of a security over a time interval.
I have no idea which is my best request type to use. 
I can not find if the HistoricalDataRequest has the ability to do this or if i would be better off trying to use the studyrequest.

If its possible with the Historical what would be the field name??? LOW(?)
I can see how to do it with the intraday using the event and getting the low but have no plan how to best do it.
My scenario is trying to get the low data for a bag of securities with different time frames.
Any help much appreciated

Comment: If on daily data you simply get the low of each day in the interval and find the smallest - for an intraday interval you need to retrieve intraday bars and make the calculation. Not sure where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi yeah, I had thought of this method. I was just hoping i could givve an interval using historical data and say give me the low of the entire interval. So the bloomberg would be doing the work with the data as opposed to transfering all the interval data for every day and then going through it. I mean from what i understand the studyrequest also allows this...

Comment: I see - have you tried HELP HELP?

Comment: I dont have a bloomberg terminal or what do you mean?